# Text input in PySimpleGUI is doubled, counts both key down and key up as input I believe

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Whenever I try to type a number (ex: 1) into my textbox, it types the number both when I press the key and when I release the key (ex: 11). All of the on screen buttons work fine, this only happens when I type with my keyboard. I am very new to programming in general so thanks for all the help.

My code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Calculator')],
    [sg.Input(size=(10,1), key='DISPLAY', justification='right')],
    [sg.Button('1'), sg.Button('2'), sg.Button('3')],
    [sg.Button('4'), sg.Button('5'), sg.Button('6')],
    [sg.Button('7'), sg.Button('8'), sg.Button('9')],
    [sg.Button('0'), sg.Button('+'), sg.Button('-')],
    [sg.Button('*'), sg.Button('/'), sg.Button('C')],
    [sg.Button('='), sg.Button('.')],
]

window = sg.Window('Calculator', layout, return_keyboard_events=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event.isdigit() or event in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:
        current_value = values['DISPLAY']
        window['DISPLAY'].update(f'{current_value}{event}')
    
    elif event == 'C':
        window['DISPLAY'].update('')
    
    elif event == '=':
        try:
            result = eval(values['DISPLAY'])
            window['DISPLAY'].update(str(result))
        except:
            window['DISPLAY'].update('Error')

window.close()
```

Comment: You did it by `window['DISPLAY'].update(f'{current_value}{event}')`, `current_value` already include the `event`.

Comment: I find it really useful to print `event` and `values` right after the `window.read()` call.   This makes it easy to see when an event happens and the values of those variables.  When debugging, it's important info.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting double hits when you enter a number via the keyboard is not because you are getting one response from key-down and another from key up. It is because when you hit a key on the keyboard it goes straight into the input element, but it also generates an event, and you are responding to that event by adding the key from that event to the input - so it appears twice.

So in your event loop you need to respond to the button presses but not to keyboard events. So just replace

```
window = sg.Window('Calculator', layout, return_keyboard_events=True)
```

with

```
window = sg.Window('Calculator', layout)
```

Also in your example the decimal point button has no effect - but that is easy to fix by adding it to your list:

```
if event.isdigit() or event in ['+', '-', '*', '/', '.']:
```